# Can't use realloc because expression must have arithmetic type

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to reallocate memory for an array and an array of pointers, molecule->atoms and molecule->atom_ptrs. Assuming that the arrays have already been malloced in a previous function, I don't know what to do. Thanks in advance!

The function is below:

```
void molappend_atom(molecule *molecule, atom *atom)
{
   // Check if the maximum number of atoms has been reached
    if (molecule->atom_no == molecule->atom_max) {
        // Double the size of the atom_max if it's not 0
        if (molecule->atom_max != 0) {
            molecule->atom_max *= 2;
        }
        // If atom_max is 0, set it to 1
        else {
            molecule->atom_max = 1;
        }
        // Reallocate memory for the atoms array
        molecule->atoms = (atom *) realloc(molecule->atoms, sizeof(atom) * molecule->atom_max);
        // Reallocate memory for the atom_ptrs array
        molecule->atom_ptrs = (atom **) realloc(molecule->atom_ptrs, sizeof(atom *) * molecule->atom_max);
    }
    // Copy the data from the input atom to the next empty space in the atoms array
    molecule->atoms[molecule->atom_no] = *atom;
    // Set the corresponding pointer in the atom_ptrs array to the added atom
    molecule->atom_ptrs[molecule->atom_no] = &molecule->atoms[molecule->atom_no];
    // Increment the atom_no counter
    molecule->atom_no++;
}
```

The Structs:

```
typedef struct atom
{
char element[3];
double x, y, z;
} atom;

typedef struct bond
{
atom *a1, *a2;
unsigned char epairs;
} bond;

typedef struct molecule
{
unsigned short atom_max, atom_no;
atom *atoms, **atom_ptrs;
unsigned short bond_max, bond_no;
bond *bonds, **bond_ptrs;
} molecule;
```

The function that initialized the arrays:

```
molecule *molmalloc(unsigned short atom_max, unsigned short bond_max)
{
    molecule *mol = (molecule *)malloc(sizeof(molecule));       // Allocate memory for a 'molecule' structure
    if (mol == NULL) 
    {      // Check if memory allocation failed
        return NULL;        // malloc failed
    }

    mol->atom_max = atom_max;       // Set the value of atom_max in the structure to the value specified in the argument
    mol->atom_no = 0;       // Set the value of atom_no in the structure to zero
    
    mol->atoms = (atom *)malloc(sizeof(atom) * atom_max);       // Allocate memory for array 'atoms' to hold atom_max atoms
    if (mol->atoms == NULL) 
    {      // Check if memory allocation failed
        free(mol);      // Frees mol structure to ensure no memory errors
        return NULL;        // malloc failed
    }

    mol->atom_ptrs = (atom **)malloc(sizeof(atom *) * atom_max);        // Allocate memory for array 'atom_ptrs'
    if (mol->atom_ptrs == NULL) 
    {      // Check if memory allocation failed
        free(mol->atoms);       // Frees array in struct before freeing struct to ensure all memory is freed 
        free(mol);      // Frees mol structure to ensure no memory errors
        return NULL;        // malloc failed
    }

    mol->bond_max = bond_max;       // Set the value of bond_max in the structure to the value specified in the argument
    mol->bond_no = 0;       // Set the value of bond_no in the structure to zero

    mol->bonds = (bond *)malloc(sizeof(bond) * bond_max);       // Allocate memory for array 'bonds' to hold bond_max bonds
    if (mol->bonds == NULL) 
    {       // Check if memory allocation failed
        free(mol->atoms);       // Frees all allocated memory in the structure to ensure no memory errors
        free(mol->atom_ptrs);   // "'"
        free(mol);              // "'"
        return NULL;        // malloc failed
    }
    mol->bond_ptrs = (bond **)malloc(sizeof(bond *) * bond_max);        // Allocates memory for array 'bond_ ptrs' NOTE: its **
    if (mol->bond_ptrs == NULL) 
    {       // Check if memory allocation failed
        free(mol->atoms);       // Frees all allocated memory in the structure to ensure no memory errors
        free(mol->atom_ptrs);
        free(mol->bonds);
        free(mol);
        return NULL;        // malloc failed
    }

    return mol;     // Returns the address of the malloced memory for the molecule
}
```

Comment: It's not nice (and it's not shown) to call `malloc()` asking for zero bytes... Leave out the `malloc`ing of atoms and bonds (and seemingly weird "ptrs") from `molmalloc()` (but be sure to initialise to NULL or 0 appropriately) and rely on `realloc()` acting like `malloc()` if the first parameter is NULL.

Comment: OT: There are elements whose chemical symbol is 3 characters long... Have you provided for those as C strings (with room for a trailing `'\0'`??)

Comment: How do yo initialize? What numbers do you provide? What does "expression must have arithmetic type" mean? If you get an error message, what is complete and exact message and where in your code do you get it?

Comment: You do not need and you also should not cast the return value of `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`. It can hide errors like failing to include required headers.

Comment: PS: You seem to be very careful about testing the return codes for the needless calls to `malloc()`, but there's no similar consideration to check the return codes from `realloc()`... Needs work...

Comment: Your code is a good example of useless comments making code *drastically less readable*. Your code would be  much better without these comments that merely restate the code without adding any information: they add a lot of visual clutter and consequently make the code that actually matters less readable. `molmalloc` in particular is really, *really* unreadable as a result.

Comment: Use comments to answer why questions or explain things that would not be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a revised version of the OP code. As this isn't an MRE, this is presented "as is", uncompiled and untested.

```
typedef struct atom {
    char element[ 3 + 1 ]; // eg: element #118 "Uuo"
    double x, y, z;
} atom;

typedef struct bond {
    // ... same as OP
} bond;

typedef struct molecule {
    // ... same as OP
} molecule;

// Allocate a molecule struct
// Note that calloc() ensures all bytes are set to 0
molecule *molmalloc( void ) {
    molecule *m = calloc( 1, sizeof *m );

    // if( m == NULL )
    //    return NULL;

    /* That's all we need to do here */
    /* Suggests the code could be inline instead of a separate function */

    return m; // Notice that 'm' may be NULL.
}

// Use this to add any atoms to a molecule:
void molappend_atom( molecule *m, atom *a ) {
    if( m->atom_no == m->atom_max) {
        m->atom_max *= 2;
        if( m->atom_max == 0 ) // yes, even the very first atom passes this way
            m->atom_max = 1;

        m->atoms = realloc( m->atoms, m->atom_max * sizeof *m->atoms );
        /* omitting test for success */
        m->atom_ptrs = realloc( m->atom_ptrs, m->atom_max * sizeof *m->atom_ptrs );
        /* omitting test for success */
    }

    m->atoms[ m->atom_no ] = *a;
    m->atom_ptrs[ m->atom_no] = &m->atoms[ m->atom_no ];
    m->atom_no++;
}
```

Not much code here. Readable.

Read the documentation for recommended usage of `realloc()` so as not to lose the original pointer should the allocation fail.